# Use webview in HoloEverywhere Activity

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-holo-everywhere

The problem is simply, when I have an activity from the HoloEverywhere library `(import org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity;)` the webview does not work, and when I use the same activity, with the same code, but importing the default activity `(import android.app.Activity;)` the webview works again.

This is an example of one activity with webview working:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Bienvenida extends Activity{

    TextView welcome;
    Button ok;

    //justificacion
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bienvenida_layout);

        //justificacion
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/letraperson.html");
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);




        ok= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btOK);
        welcome=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuerido_lector);
        Typeface person = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "letrapaa.ttf");

        String button = new String(ok.getText().toString());
        ok.setText(button, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        SpannableString okee = (SpannableString) ok.getText();
        okee.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(204, 0, 0)), 0, 1, 0);

        //TextView person:...
        String user = new String (welcome.getText().toString());
        welcome.setText( user, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE );
        SpannableString s = (SpannableString)welcome.getText();
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(204, 0, 0)), 0, 1, 0);



        welcome.setTypeface(person);
        ok.setTypeface(person);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("CREARUSUARIO_CAMPAYO");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But if I want to custom that activity to have holo theme on 2.1+ phones, I need to extend that activity from `org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity` instead `android.app.Activity`.

So... when I extend an activity from HoloEverywhere library the following happens:

a) if I have not a webview in that activity, everything works perfectly.

b) if I have a webview in that activity, that activity does not work.

Then I have to choose between having the Holo theme or have a webview (where I can justify text for example, which I can not do with a Textview)

Does anyone know how to use webview in one activity of HoloEverywhere?

Comment: I think you need to enable hardware acceleration at Activity level.

Comment: can you say me how? @AliImran

Comment: what do you mean by not work, not load or something else. also check that the super function is called in onCreate function of the activity? it should be the first line of the code.